# asp.net Session variables inside of SharePoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

So, here is a problem that I am having with asp.net app inside of SharePoint (as page viewer).

When the Default page is loaded, it works fine.  However, when I try to go to next page, i am getting a null reference exception.  It looks like my session variables are becoming null on the next page (even though I set them on the previous page).  Here are a couple things that I tried to diagnose the problem.

1. I try on the couple other computers; some work fine, some still don’ts.
2. In the property of the page viewer inside of the SharePoint, after I click on the "Test link", it started to work fine until the session expired (on the computer didn’t work initially).

I am not sure if there are settings that I need to check on the browser or the app server.
Anyone had similar problem?

Comment: when you say "try to go to the next page" are you referring to another sharepoint page or a page inside the page viewer web part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Sharepoint, but it sounds like either In Proc session state, and the application pool restarts, a webfarm not setup properly, or cookies not being stored correctly. A starter would be to install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see which cookies are sent. Then you should install some logging mechanism in your global.asax to know if your application pool restarts. (Might show up in the event viewer as-is, don't remember.)